# Какой элемент управления использовать?

Tags: c#, winforms

Необходимо расположить несколько контролов в каждую ячейку таблицы для того, чтобы вывести информацию о книге (несколько label'ов и один picture box). Пытался использовать tableLayoutPanel, но он не подходит т.к. в каждую ячейку можно поместить только один элемент.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте TableLayoutPanel, в ячейки вставляйте [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx), а в Panel уже вставляйте другие компоненты.

Comment: Спасибо! Уже поступил так) Но возник еще один вопрос. Как динамически удалить все контролы с tableLayoutPanel?

Comment: Дочерние компоненты объекта типа TableLayoutPanel хранятся в коллекции [Controls][1]. Там есть соответствующие методы.


    [1]http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.controls.aspx

Comment: Не выходит, удаляются только элементы одного столбца.

Comment: А как насчёт метода Clear? Вроде всё сразу должен удалить.